# getElementById is null?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So my code seems to always give me this in console without even executing anything outside of this loop:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

The thing is though that this is perfectly legitimate code, it works when I enter it alone or pair it with a random number. Heck, it even outputs all the right things but the rest of my scripts don't even execute with the error so I don't understand. This isn't a one in a lifetime thing since this has happened before on the same project. What's going on? If you want to test, set num to 0 and create some dummy elements.

```
$('[id^=strip]').each(function() {
    var element = document.getElementById("stripprice" + num);

    prices[num] = element.innerHTML;

    console.log(prices[num]);

    num++;

})
```

Comment: What if the element id starts with "strip" but isn't "strippriceXX"? then `element` will be null

Comment: where does `num` come from?

Comment: It works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/sqywenu5/

Comment: Please provide a fiddle that highlights the exact problem.

Comment: To avoid getting the error, make sure you have a series of elements with **id="strippriceX"** with x being consecutive integers from **"num" to N**. And also make sure you have no other elements that also match the selector **'[id^=strip]'**

Answer (score 0):

**Overall in the future I guess what one needs to do in this kind of situation is to ensure to remove or comment out any elements that you know are not setup yet as to not cause any confusion to the JS and of course the programmer (you).**

Thanks for your help guys. It's my fault. I had to go through a whole lot of trouble to finish my HTML but I realized that this entire issue was caused by the fact that it was scanning the elements I already added, but the rest were undefined. Literally. They weren't there and for the ones that were there, many of them were not numbered correctly because I C+Ped them for testing purposes.